# Show cities near me within x kilometers

Tags: android, ios, sql, flutter

I am building an app where I would like to display the cities near me according the number of kilometers done by a user. So if I do 200 km, the app should be able to display major cities within 200 kilometers.

My developers are using the Google maps API, however we are stuck to a point where the api displays only places and those places are not only cities but businesses, schools etc which is not what we want.

Does anyone has an idea of what we need to do in our code to display only cities according the km done by a user ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You would probably need to create your own or obtain a list of major cities and their locations. Once you have this in a database the rest is pretty easy.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, thank you for your response. Do you mean that after obtaining a list of major cities and locations, we just need to create a code to show them according the kilometers made by a user ?

Comment: I mean that you will need to create your own database of cities with latitude and longitude values. Querying that data against a user location should be pretty simple.